# Force waterfall hydration on getResult

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

I have an entity that is called 'Video', and attached to it, are other entities associated by ManyToOne and ManyToMany.

My problem, is that the amount of queries being executed is getting on the wrong side of uncomfortable with regular traffic. For instance, I have a variable amount of Queries being executed on the front page, and was getting to about 49 queries.

The extreme majority of the queries being executed were because the sub-entities to my Video entity are not being initialized automatically when called. When Dumped, I see a private property "is_initialized" set to 0. When called in my template, as they tend to be reported, Doctrine then executes the query to get that data.

I understand why Doctrine does this, if that data isn't being used, why get it in the first place? In the majority of cases, this behaviour is fine.

But in my case, I have a few methods in my `VideoRepository` class for fetching specific sets of videos. So I am using DQL here. In response, I decided to set the Result Cache to Apc right in the DQL.

Here's a relatively harmless example from the repository

```
    /**
     * Get Videos based on recently submitted
     *
     * @param null $limit
     * @param int $page
     * @return array
     */
    public function latest($limit = null, $page = 1)
    {
        $hash = md5(sprintf("%s_%s", $limit, $page));

        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $query->select('v')->from($this->getEntityName(), 'v')
            ->where('v.published = :published')
            ->orderBy('v.datePublished', 'DESC')
            ->setParameter('published', true);

        if($limit) {
            $query->setFirstResult((int)(($page-1) * $limit));
            $query->setMaxResults($limit);
        }

        $resultQuery = $query->getQuery();
        $resultQuery->setResultCacheDriver(new ApcCache())->useResultCache(true, 300, sprintf('results_latest.%s', $hash));

        return $resultQuery->getResult();
    }
```

So on the front page (where the 49 queries are being executed, more to come once production data starts hitting) there are 10 videos being requested from this method.

Inside of each video, is an associated "Product" entity (ManyToMany).  In each video's thumbnail display, is a little Product icon, so naturally I need to access the `$product` property containing the Product Entity from the Video entity.

At this point, it's executing 10 more queries, because Doctrine never bothered to fetch the Product data for each video, and so it creates a query for each icon I ask for, which beings us up to 11 (minimum, ManyToMany means each Video can be associated with more than one product).  There are 3 more strips of Videos queried for on this page for differing lists, using different methods in the `VideoRepository`

The problem here, is that while the Caching system works to store the result data of each main query for 5 minutes, it's also stashing that the Product and other Embedded Entities have not been acquired.

So with simple math, this means using the cache system has only saved me 4 queries, bringing my Doctrine query count to 45.

Is there a simple way to tell Doctrine to sub-query and auto-hydrate for ALL of the sub-entities when using getResult?

Comment: left joining the product data will cause it be loaded on the initial query.  You can also set fetch=eager on your associations (or even globally) but you probably don't really want to do that.  http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html?highlight=eager

Comment: hmm when I set the `products` property to `Eager`, it doesn't seem to cache the result when executing the query :\

Comment: I don't use the Doctrine caching stuff myself so I can't help you there.  Your tag indicates that you are using Symfony 2 so you might try their caching.  It's quite extensive.  And don't forget to clear the Symfony cache when you make Doctrine association changes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, change your query to select more entities and doctrine will need fewer lazy loads.

```
$query->select('v', 'sub', 'others')
        ->from($this->getEntityName(), 'v')
        ->leftJoin('v.subtitles','sub')
        ->leftJoin('v.others','others')
        ->where('v.published = :published')
        ->orderBy('v.datePublished', 'DESC')
        ->setParameter('published', true);
```

This will return more data and doctrine will not have successive queries every time you need a subtitle or some other entity.  As a warning, this will return more data so make sure this method is acceptable.

Comment: I think this should be more than acceptable, just sad it has to be explicitly specifying the join, rather than enabling a setting to do perform waterfall hydration or deep hydration automatically

Comment: The problem with a global setting (which Doctrine 2 does have) is that there is an unfortunate tendency to end up accidentally loading the entire database.

Comment: I did a combo of this and some well placed `fetch="Eagers"`, but the leftJoin by itself unfortunately did not hydrate the entities.

I ended up just using DQL to get all results, hydrate and invoke as I need for required information, and just used the ApcCache Driver that Doctrine2 provides, to store the end results in.  Seems to work quite well!

Comment: If you are going into that much detail, and performance is a requirement, you may want to do a partial query to select only the specific fields from the entities you are querying.  It only makes a difference if you have one field that is not needed and holds a lot of data.  I have geometries in one of my tables and some geometries have hundreds of points.  Using partials sped up my query drastically.